# Python: How to check if a cell has a formula to calculate it's value or not using openpyxl?

Tags: python-2.7, excel-formula, openpyxl

I am working with an excel sheet using openpyxl library in python. I want to check whether a cell has formula to calculate it's value. Actually all cells in a particular column has a formula to calculate their values. I want to copy the value of a cell to another sheet if this cell has a formula.

Comment: `data_type` = 'f'`

Comment: Thanks Charlie. It helped me.

Comment: @aniruddhsharma If [daanav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54142839/320399) addresses your question, you should should mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly how are you loading the Workbook? Are you loading with `data_only`set to `True` or without it? As this will make a difference.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("MyBook.xlsx", data_only=True)
```

If you have opened it with `data_only=True` then I don't know a way to find out if the cell contains a formula.

But you can open it with `data_only=False` and then if you get the value of the cell `wb["Sheet1"].cell(row,column).value` you will see the formula or if `wb["Sheet1"].cell(row,column).data_type` returns *'f'* then the cell contains a formula.